# how to make sure a link is clicked with watir-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using [watir](http://watir.com/) to perform some functions

I need to show that a link is actually clicked by the watir-driver, so I'm trying to `put` somthing to the console if a link is clicked as follow:

```
puts "profile clicked" if click_my_profile_link(browser)
```

and:

```
 def self.click_my_profile_link(browser)
    browser.div(class: "topbar").when_present
      .link(class: 'my-profile').click
  end
```

but nothing gets printed to the console when the link gets clicked. this behaviour is the same for everywhere I have a click action. Another example is:

```
puts "Next button clicked" if browser.input(id: 'next', value: 'Next').fire_event :click
```

How can I get some kind of log when there is a click action fired like this? thanks

Comment: Are you using a testing framework that provides assertions/expectations and reporting (e.g. rspec)?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into it.  That way, you get a mechanism to A) verify expected application behavior; and B) produce reports (often in a variety of formats).  Typically, it's not necessary to validate when a link is clicked.  That's an implicit expectation that would be exposed when the subsequent step failed.  But YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedural methods are called for their action/side-effect and shouldn't be expected to have a response.

If you didn't get an error, then Watir found the element and sent a click command to it.

So maybe this is sufficient `expect {click_my_profile_link(browser)}.to_not raise_error`

Typically you write tests to verify the result of the link. In this case that would be something like `expect(browser.title == "My Profile Title").to be true`

You could create an AfterHook that will take an additional action after every navigation and click, but it wouldn't distinguish between the two, and I really don't think that is what you actually want.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this. Your explanation that `If you didn't get an error, then Watir found the element and sent a click command to it` is the confirmation  that helped me.